# Python: Custom Exceptions with a embedded error handling routine?

Tags: python

Is it a bad idea to implement my own exceptions with special error handling/logging system embedded? I wish to concentrate some of my error handling stuff in just one place.

For example:

**errors.py**

```
class ReallyBadException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, msg, error_handling):
        super(Exception, self).__init__(msg)
        ...
        error_handling.logger.error(msg)
        error_handling.db.do_stuff(msg)
        call_the_police()
        ...
```

Obviously I know I still will need to handle the exception locally in the main function etc

**main.py**

```
from errors import ReallyBadException, NotSoBadException, ...
...  
try: 
    do_something()
except RellyBadException:
    do_another_thing()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, no this is not a bad idea at all.

In fact, the way I see it, what you're trying to do is ultimately reason why programming languages have exception handling in the first place.